# How to parse the files by name?

Tags: shell, awk, scripting

I have files like this in my folder

```
262_V01_C07_R099_THx_BH_4096H.dat~   birrp.5.pdf          diagnostic.f      junho.1n1.rp  junho.1r2.rp  junho.2r.2c2  Makefile~      nilton.1n2.rp  nilton.2n.2c2  nilton.diag    weight.f
AdvProExampleScript_pb01.script      birrp.f              ewerton.diag      junho.1n.2c2  junho.2n1.rf  junho.2r2.rf  math.f         nilton.1r1.rf  nilton.2n2.rf  nilton.j       wrthx
BasicModeExampleScript_pb01.script   birrp.tar            ewerton.j         junho.1n2.rf  junho.2n1.rp  junho.2r2.rp  mimi.diag      nilton.1r1.rp  nilton.2n2.rp  parameters.h   wrthx.f90
BasicModeExampleScript_pb01.script~  calibration2401.txt  fft.f             junho.1n2.rp  junho.2n.2c2  junho.diag    mimi.j         nilton.1r.2c2  nilton.2r1.rf  parameters.h~  wrthx.f90~
bbcalfunc.py                         Calibration Files    filter.f          junho.1r1.rf  junho.2n2.rf  junho.j       nilton.1n1.rf  nilton.1r2.rf  nilton.2r1.rp  rarfilt.f      zlinpack.f
bbcalfunc.py~                        coherence.f          hx.sens           junho.1r1.rp  junho.2n2.rp  karn.diag     nilton.1n1.rp  nilton.1r2.rp  nilton.2r.2c2  response.f
bin                                  dat                  inputxgarcia.txt  junho.1r.2c2  junho.2r1.rf  karn.j        nilton.1n.2c2  nilton.2n1.rf  nilton.2r2.rf  rtpss.f
birrp                                dataft.f             junho.1n1.rf      junho.1r2.rf  junho.2r1.rp  Makefile      nilton.1n2.rf  nilton.2n1.rp  nilton.2r2.rp  utils.f
```

I would like to separate them,so how should I write a script that will print on screen all `nilton` files?I have tried with `awk` but it is not working.

Comment: Er...you don't just mean `ls nilton.*`, do you?

Comment: @Wintermute Yes I meant this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a portable POSIX shell solution that uses no outside utilities:

```
#!/bin/sh 
for i in *
do  case "$i" in
        nilton*) 
            printf "%s\n" "$i"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: This will break in silly ways if one of the file names contains a `%` character. It is also rather convoluted. `printf '%s\n' nilton.*` would be a saner replacement.